# Cannot connect to SFTP server

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, sftp

I am moving two Windows Server 2008 R2 servers to two new Windows Server 2012 Standard servers.

From these servers we need to connect to two different SFTP servers to upload files.

I can connect to one of the SFTP servers as expected. The other one does not. I've been in contact with the owner of that server and they have stated that they have no restrictions (ie. specific incoming ip address). I have verified this by connecting to the server in question from 2 other Windows 10 machines.

I've turned off the firewall to makes sure it was not blocking any traffic. Same results.

Here is a log of the attempted connection:

```
. 2018-11-16 12:48:01.467 Looking up host "Copaftp.state.pa.us" for SSH connection
. 2018-11-16 12:48:01.467 Connecting to 164.156.185.23 port 22
. 2018-11-16 12:48:01.514 Selecting events 63 for socket 1360
. 2018-11-16 12:48:01.514 We claim version: SSH-2.0-WinSCP_release_5.13.4
. 2018-11-16 12:48:01.545 Waiting for the server to continue with the initialization
. 2018-11-16 12:48:01.545 Looking for incoming data
. 2018-11-16 12:48:01.545 Looking for network events
. 2018-11-16 12:48:01.545 Detected network event
. 2018-11-16 12:48:01.545 Enumerating network events for socket 1360
. 2018-11-16 12:48:01.545 Enumerated 18 network events making 18 cumulative events for socket 1360
. 2018-11-16 12:48:01.545 Handling network write event on socket 1360 with error 0
. 2018-11-16 12:48:01.545 Handling network connect event on socket 1360 with error 0
. 2018-11-16 12:48:01.545 Looking for network events
. 2018-11-16 12:48:01.561 Detected network event
. 2018-11-16 12:48:01.561 Enumerating network events for socket 1360
. 2018-11-16 12:48:01.561 Enumerated 32 network events making 32 cumulative events for socket 1360
. 2018-11-16 12:48:01.561 Handling network close event on socket 1360 with error 0
. 2018-11-16 12:48:01.561 Selecting events 0 for socket 1360
. 2018-11-16 12:48:01.561 Server unexpectedly closed network connection
. 2018-11-16 12:48:01.561 Knocking FTP port.
. 2018-11-16 12:48:01.608 FTP port opened, will suggest using FTP protocol.
* 2018-11-16 12:48:01.623 (EFatal) Server unexpectedly closed network connection.
* 2018-11-16 12:48:01.623 The server rejected SFTP connection, but it listens for FTP connections.
```

What am I missing? Makes no sense that I can connect to the one SFTP server and not this one. (The only difference in the configuration between these two connections is the host name and credentials.) However I can connect to the SFTP server in question with no problems from other systems.

Is this an issue with Windows Server 2012 network stack? Btw, I get the same result on both of the new servers.

Comment: I just tried connecting to the SFTP server from another AWS EC2 instance running Windows Server 2012 R2, and it connects as expected.